# Azure Function Nuget Cache restore failing with "The user name or password is incorrect."

Tags: azure, nuget-package, azure-functions, nuget-package-restore

I have an Azure Function I deploy as a part of an ARM template. This Azure Function references a few external .NET DLLs. I have added the reference to these DLLs in the project.json file:

project.json:

```
{
    "frameworks": {
        "net46": {
            "dependencies": {
                "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory":"3.13.8",
                "Newtonsoft.Json":  "10.0.2",
                 "Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies" : "8.2.0.2" 
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

When I click run, the Nuget Cache restore is kicked off. It fails with "The user name or password is incorrect."

The strange thing is the Nuget Packages are being copied to the Functions Nuget cache correctly, but the project.lock.json file is failing to be created. It appears the username / password error is thrown after the Nuget cache restore completes and when Azure tries to write the project.lock.json file. The compile then fails as the project.lock.json file is not created.

```
2017-11-14T21:06:34.892 Restoring packages.
2017-11-14T21:06:34.892 Starting NuGet restore
2017-11-14T21:06:36.239 Function started (Id=1340feea-174d-4bee-97f2-e06afc2e2d6e)
2017-11-14T21:06:36.239 Package references have been updated.
2017-11-14T21:06:36.239 Restoring packages.
2017-11-14T21:06:36.239 Starting NuGet restore
2017-11-14T21:06:36.955 Restoring packages for D:\home\site\wwwroot\ProvisionUserToCRM\project.json...
2017-11-14T21:06:37.456 CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory/index.json
2017-11-14T21:06:37.486 CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory/3.13.8/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.3.13.8.nupkg
2017-11-14T21:06:37.705 CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/newtonsoft.json/index.json
2017-11-14T21:06:37.705 CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/newtonsoft.json/10.0.2/newtonsoft.json.10.0.2.nupkg
2017-11-14T21:06:37.800 CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.crmsdk.coreassemblies/index.json
2017-11-14T21:06:37.800 CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.crmsdk.coreassemblies/8.2.0.2/microsoft.crmsdk.coreassemblies.8.2.0.2.nupkg
2017-11-14T21:06:37.881 CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.identitymodel/index.json
2017-11-14T21:06:37.881 CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.identitymodel/6.1.7600.16394/microsoft.identitymodel.6.1.7600.16394.nupkg
2017-11-14T21:06:38.002 Installing Microsoft.IdentityModel 6.1.7600.16394.
2017-11-14T21:06:38.362 Installing Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies 8.2.0.2.
2017-11-14T21:06:38.939 Restoring packages for D:\home\site\wwwroot\ProvisionUserToCRM\project.json...
2017-11-14T21:06:39.113 Installing Newtonsoft.Json 10.0.2.
2017-11-14T21:06:39.255 CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory/index.json
2017-11-14T21:06:39.284 CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory/3.13.8/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.3.13.8.nupkg
2017-11-14T21:06:39.455 CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/newtonsoft.json/index.json
2017-11-14T21:06:39.455 CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/newtonsoft.json/10.0.2/newtonsoft.json.10.0.2.nupkg
2017-11-14T21:06:39.470 CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.crmsdk.coreassemblies/index.json
2017-11-14T21:06:39.470 CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.crmsdk.coreassemblies/8.2.0.2/microsoft.crmsdk.coreassemblies.8.2.0.2.nupkg
2017-11-14T21:06:39.490 CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.identitymodel/index.json
2017-11-14T21:06:39.502 CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.identitymodel/6.1.7600.16394/microsoft.identitymodel.6.1.7600.16394.nupkg
2017-11-14T21:06:39.642 Installing Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory 3.13.8.
2017-11-14T21:06:41.211 Installing Microsoft.IdentityModel 6.1.7600.16394.
2017-11-14T21:06:42.367 Installing Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies 8.2.0.2.
2017-11-14T21:06:46.398 Installing Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory 3.13.8.
2017-11-14T21:06:49.197 Installing Newtonsoft.Json 10.0.2.
2017-11-14T21:06:52.171 The user name or password is incorrect.
2017-11-14T21:06:52.189 
2017-11-14T21:06:52.189 
2017-11-14T21:06:52.189 Packages restored.
2017-11-14T21:06:52.500 Script for function 'ProvisionUserToCRM' changed. Reloading.
2017-11-14T21:06:52.813 run.csx(2,18): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'IdentityModel' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2017-11-14T21:06:52.813 run.csx(3,8): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Does anyone know why this error is displayed? It seems to come intermittently for me. Seems like a bug in Azure Functions. Are there any known work arounds?

I found enabling 'Slots' preview feature on Azure Functions actually resolves this issue, but 'Slots' will not work for me as they are not compatible with Azure Logic Apps.

Comment: I have opened an issue at https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/590  We are actively investigating this issue.

Comment: I am getting this same error when the function tries to restore the nuget packages. My packages are Microsoft.Cognitive.CustomVision.Prediction and Microsoft.Cognitive.CustomVision.Training. Can also confirm activating slots got me past that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like Microsoft has confirmed this is a bug in Azure Functions
https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/590

The only work around I am aware of is to:

- enable slots feature
- keep re deploying your ARM template until it works
- (I did not verify this) but I suspect it would work if you manually generated and dropped the lock file to the Functions file system. You could generate the lock file locally with visual studio. I suspect this would work because from what I observed is the NuGet packages seem to be restored correctly, and the error comes during the write of the JSON file. The compiler must reference the lock file rather than the actual NuGet cache when trying to compile (hence why the error is coming even though the DLL actually exists).